# Gamification for knowledge management database or not?

Tags: gamification, data-collection

I wonder if gamification will produce a lot of content only for the purpose of creating content and playing, receiving badges etc.
You're all experts for that question, since you are using stack exchange. ;-)

We have a very well appreciated knowledge management (KM) system at work (~7000 colleagues) with presentations, tips of the day, some sort of social networking tool (profieles to find experts etc.) and a database that supports the KM. I am part of the central team providing this and improving wherever we can.

Is it worth to add some gamification?
E. g. we could create badges like here on stack exchange etc.
This will cost money, time etc.
We would like to teach more people (~ 1/3) is reached by now.  But we also always need new authors for tips of the day and knowledge agents filling the database.

Thanks for your thoughts and feedback.

Comment: The gamification on StackExchange is one of the things that keeps me coming back. It is nice to have the approval of one's peers. And since one can be downvoted as well as upvoted, it means people don't comment just for the sake of commenting, but try to give good quality answers that are actually helpful and worthy of an upvote.

Comment: As with most answers; "it depends". Gamification is a tool. It has to be used properly to have any effect at all. Don't reward content creation: reward creation of QUALITY content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it worth it to add some gamification?

Yes, but do some research first.  Gamification done poorly can backfire.  In the links below, each one describes successes AND failures.  I don't think you'd ask this question if you had already dug deep into gamification, so let me share a few of the resources I enjoyed:

## Online Classes

The online classes I've enjoyed because I can listen to them on my drive, and then re-watch the critical portions when I can look at the screen too.

1. [Coursera has a free course on gamification (click for link)](https://www.coursera.org/learn/gamification)

   The course is sponsored by University of Pennsylvania, and the content is exceptional, especially for the price (free).
2. [Udemy has Gabe Zichermann's Gamification Level 1](https://www.udemy.com/designing-gamification-level-1-certification)

   Gabe is the defacto global ambassador of gamification.  His courses are good, and his connections are amazing.  The "bonus" lectures from his guest speakers will expand your thinking tremendously.  There is also a level 2 class, with diminishing returns, course 1 is better, but both are valuable (Each class is a pay class $15 when on best sale, $49 full retail)
3. [Udemy has Mario Herger's Enterprise Gamification](https://www.udemy.com/enterprise-gamification/)

   Mario runs an excellent blog on gamification, and is a well-known enterprise gamification Guru.  You'll want to get some fundamentals before you take his course, but his perspectives fill in a lot of the gaps and give some great ideas.  ($15 best sale, $29 full retail)

## Web Links

1. [Gamification.Co](http://www.gamification.co/)

   Gabe's website is full of blog entries, video resources, and books on gamification.  It's a great starting point.
2. [Enterprise Garage](http://www.enterprisegarage.io/)

   Mario's main website.  He has a lot of resources here on enterprise gamification.  He has two other websites that are not consolidated into this one yet that are also worth looking at: [Enterprise-Gamification](http://enterprise-gamification.com/index.php?lang=en) and [Mario's Site](http://www.marioherger.at/)
3. [Badgeville's Case Studies](https://badgeville.com/category/case-studies/)

   These case studies are really interesting learning on some very specific gaming initiatives, and how they helped companies make a big difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Quite some good suggestions to start digging deeper in the topic.

Answer (score 3):

The following are worthy readings about this matter.

(1) A good article to start digging and understanding gamification for business:

**The Evolution of Gamification in the Workplace, by Sharlyn Lauby**
http://mashable.com/2012/06/15/gamification-business-evolution/#48Neotarzsqb

(2) For those looking for a deep knowledge about gamification at working places, this book from Interaction Design Foundation is highly recommended:

**Gamification at Work: Designing Engaging Business Software, by Janaki Kumar and Mario Herger**
https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/book/gamification-at-work-designing-engaging-business-software?ep=cv

I hope it helps anybody looking for this subject :-)